# How to pass values from an aspx page to HTML page?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html

I've a `Login.aspx` page. After successfully logging in, I'm redirecting it to `Welcome.html` page located in another project. Now, I want a jquery modal box to appear on HTML page containing message "Welcome USERNAME" when user logs in successfully. How can I retrieve  USERNAME entered on `Login.aspx` page? I think JQuery is the solution for this, but I've no idea how to implement this. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass it in url

like `Welcome.html?username=Prateek`

in **Welcome.html**
use jquery to get url parameter value (*username*)

```
 <script >
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var x = getParameterByName("username"); ///get url parameter value
    alert("username : " + x);
    function getParameterByName(name) {
            name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
            var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
                results = regex.exec(location.search);
            return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the welcome.html page an aspx (if you are able to do so) and then you can use the `User` object which I believe is called like this:

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

Here are the Msdn references:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.user.aspx